# change class of li from server side in custom control

Tags: asp.net, html-lists, server-side, custom-server-controls

Hi i have created a server control which consists of  **`<UL>`**  and its  **`<LI>`**
I just wanted to reuse my menu in all six pages

 below is controls code
Asp Code

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" ClassName="Menu" %>
     <ul id="ulSideBar" class="nav nav-list" runat="server">
                <li accesskey="1" id="liDefault" runat="server" **class="active"**>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkDefault" OnClick="lnkDefault_Click">Introduction</asp:LinkButton></li>
                <li accesskey="2" id="liSquad" runat="server">
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkSquad" OnClick="lnkSquad_Click">Squad</asp:LinkButton>
                </li>
                <li accesskey="3" id="liGallery" runat="server">
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkGallery" OnClick="lnkGallery_Click">Gallery</asp:LinkButton>
                </li>
                <li accesskey="4" id="liMatches" runat="server">
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkMatches" OnClick="lnkMatches_Click">Matches</asp:LinkButton>
                </li>
                <li accesskey="5" id="liActivities" runat="server">
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkActivities" OnClick="lnkActivities_Click">Activities</asp:LinkButton>
                </li>
                <li accesskey="6" id="liNewsFeed" runat="server">
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkNewsFeed" OnClick="lnkNewsFeed_Click">News Feed</asp:LinkButton>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Im using this control in my six pages Now my question is how can i change **class=active** whichever **`<li>`** I click, only through server side

I have tried this code in Control's codebehind but its not working

```
 protected void lnkDefault_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        liDefault.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        liSquad.Attributes.Remove("class");
        liGallery.Attributes.Remove("class");
        liMatches.Attributes.Remove("class");
        liActivities.Attributes.Remove("class");
        liNewsFeed.Attributes.Remove("class");
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
    protected void lnkSquad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        liDefault.Attributes.Remove("class");
        liSquad.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        liGallery.Attributes.Remove("class");
        liMatches.Attributes.Remove("class");
        liActivities.Attributes.Remove("class");
        liNewsFeed.Attributes.Remove("class");
        Response.Redirect("Squad.aspx");
    }
    protected void lnkGallery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        liSquad.Attributes.Remove("class");
        liDefault.Attributes.Remove("class");
        liGallery.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        liMatches.Attributes.Remove("class");
        liActivities.Attributes.Remove("class");
        liNewsFeed.Attributes.Remove("class");
        Response.Redirect("Gallery.aspx");
    }
    protected void lnkMatches_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        liDefault.Attributes.Remove("class");
        liSquad.Attributes.Remove("class");
        liGallery.Attributes.Remove("class");
        liMatches.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        liActivities.Attributes.Remove("class");
        liNewsFeed.Attributes.Remove("class");
        Response.Redirect("Matches.aspx");
    }
    protected void lnkActivities_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        liDefault.Attributes.Remove("class");
        liSquad.Attributes.Remove("class");
        liGallery.Attributes.Remove("class");
        liMatches.Attributes.Remove("class");
        liActivities.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        liNewsFeed.Attributes.Remove("class");
        Response.Redirect("Activities.aspx");
    }
    protected void lnkNewsFeed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        liDefault.Attributes.Remove("class");
        liSquad.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        liGallery.Attributes.Remove("class");
        liMatches.Attributes.Remove("class");
        liActivities.Attributes.Remove("class");
        liNewsFeed.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        Response.Redirect("NewsFeed.aspx");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solved my problem. My problem was i was using a custom control having `<ul>` `<li>` but the page where the control was used had a problem ie when user click li it should change its class to active (class='active') but due to post back it was not changing 
 
May be if someone else has this problem can use my solution. I used this function in my custom control codebehind

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // switch (Parent.TemplateControl.AppRelativeVirtualPath.Replace("~/Teams/", ""))
            switch (System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Page.Request.Path))
            {
                case "Default.aspx":
                    liDefault.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
                    liSquad.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    liGallery.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    liMatches.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    liActivities.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    liNewsFeed.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    break;
                case "Squad.aspx":
                    liDefault.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    liSquad.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
                    liGallery.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    liMatches.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    liActivities.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    liNewsFeed.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    break;
                case "Gallery.aspx":
                    liSquad.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    liDefault.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    liGallery.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
                    liMatches.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    liActivities.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    liNewsFeed.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    break;
                case "Matches.aspx":
                    liDefault.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    liSquad.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    liGallery.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    liMatches.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
                    liActivities.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    liNewsFeed.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    break;
                case "Activities.aspx":
                    liDefault.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    liSquad.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    liGallery.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    liMatches.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    liActivities.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
                    liNewsFeed.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    break;
                case "NewsFeed.aspx":
                    liDefault.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    liSquad.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    liGallery.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    liMatches.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    liActivities.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    liNewsFeed.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be changing the class attribute but then you immediately redirect to another page so you never see it.  When the page is reloaded, the change is lost.

You'll probably need to store the active page in a session variable and then when the control loads, set the active class.

[Edit]
If you want the control to reflect what page it is on maybe you could use the title of the page (or one of the other Page attributes):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Parent.Page.Title == "My Title")
    {
    }
```

Comment: your answer is acceptable but i cannot use session anyother option

Comment: @skhurams  Thanks, I added a suggestion to my answer.

Comment: thanks to you,  i found a better solution System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Page.Request.Path) this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do either way check your brower's URL and make selectoion in your menu

```
string page = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath);
string pageDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath);

string category = Request.QueryString.Count>0 ? Request.QueryString[0] : string.Empty;

switch (category)
{
    case "home":
        lnk_Home.CssClass = "selected";
        break;
}
```